# Is the form already open?

Tags: delphi

I have been using the following code to check if a form already exists:

```
function FormExists(apForm: TObject): boolean;
var i: Word;
begin
  Result := False;
  for i := 0 to Application.ComponentCount-1 do
    if Application.Components[i] = apForm then begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

I got it some years ago from a project I participated in. It was one of my first Delphi projects.

It works.

But this week I got wandering if there is a better, faster way to do this.

Comment: Has this function ever returned false? If so in what condition? Asking because it is unclear what do you mean with 'exists'.

Comment: Yes It does. If the form is not created.

Comment: Well, as you've already mentioned in a comment just test for Asssigned.

Comment: @Sertac, but if you don't use `FreeAndNil` the form variable can be assigned but the window can be destroyed. It must have also a valid handle for its *existence*.

Comment: @TLama - I think I get it. But I wouldn't test for window handle on a dangling pointer. I myself assign nil to the global variable in OnDestroy.

Comment: @Sertac, that's right. So now as safest I can see either `nil` the form variable and test for `Assigned` as you said, or if you're not doing this, iterate the `Screen.Forms`. Deleting my post...

Comment: For the life of me I cannot understand why there is so much debate and vast swathes of code when all you need is aForm<>nil

Comment: And as a complete aside, why do you assume that Application must own the form? The majority of my forms have no owner at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Screen.Forms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.Forms) for that instead. It lessens the items you're iterating through:

```
function FormExists(apForm: TForm): boolean;
var 
  i: Word;
begin
  Result := False;
  for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
    if Screen.Forms[i] = apForm then 
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

However, it's worth noting that if you have `apForm` already, you know it exists and there's no need to be searching for it.

Comment: But that is the case. In some cases I don't know. to the rest I use "Assigned".

Comment: @Jlouro, then simply `nil` the global form variable like [`Sertac said`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943695/is-the-form-already-open#comment15912082_11943695) to use the `Assigned` test or use this kind of iteration. It wouldn't be safe to ask for a valid handle of an already released control's variable.

Answer (score -4):

I found that the best way to do this is to ask the form itself if it is open.  You can do so with a CLASS procedure/function.  It is safe to call a class procedure/function of a form even if it doesn't exist.

add a class function to your form's public desclaration.

```
  type
    TForm2 = class(TForm)
      ...
    private
      { Private declarations }
      ...
    public
      { Public declarations }
      class function FormExists:  Boolean;
    end;

  class function TForm2.FormExists: Boolean;
  var
     F: TForm2;
     I: Integer;
  begin
     F := nil;
     for i := Screen.FormCount - 1 DownTo 0 do
      if (Screen.Forms[i].Name = 'Form2') then
      begin
         F := Screen.Forms[I] As TForm2;
         break;
      end;
     Result :=  F <> nil;
  end;
```

So from any unit that has Form2 in the uses clause can call

```
     if Form2.FormExists then
        ...
```

Comment: -1. This is the totally wrong solution. It ties your code to a specific form name. You **never** test against `Name`; it makes everything too specific, and makes your code unable to be re-used elsewhere.

Comment: In addition to Ken's comment, you don't need `F` and `F <> nil`, you already have a boolean; `Result`. Set Result to False at start, in the 'if' test in the 'for' loop, set Result to True and break.

Comment: @KenWhite It straight forward object oriented approach to this.  The form object can tell you itself if it is open or not.  In your approach you need to know and provide a piece of data about the form in question.  The added benefit to this approach, that I use is that with F, if it isn't nil, is a reference to the form itself, and you can check the status of your form's components.  I use it to know if a document I'm working on has been modified, and if so, I bring the form forward, and present the user with the option to save.  Something your approach would have difficult time accomplishing.

Comment: Hard-coding a reference to 'Name = 'Form2'` is like tatooing the name of your first girlfriend on a private part of your body. Fine if you always date a woman with the same name, but really bad otherwise. You **never** hard-code a name reference - ever. Did I mention **never ever**? Your code is wrong. It has nothing to do with "object orientation" - it's **bad code** to hard-code a reference to a specific name. It breaks: `var MyForm: TForm2; ... MyForm := TForm2.Create(nil); MyForm.Name := 'Mary';`, and your code no longer works.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz As I mention to Ken, I use F as a reference to the form, which gives me access to the form's components, and I can check status of items of interest.

Comment: @KenWhite it's hard coded in the form itself, where you know the form name.  Much like you code Edit1.Text := '...';

Comment: @KenWhite Not true, I have an application that can have dozens of the same form open, each one is a word processing form, that can have different documents loaded.  When the application is closed, I call this class function once, and EVERY open form is checked to see if the editor has been saved, if not, it brings the form forward, and asks to be saved or cancel.  When finished, it continues to the next form.  Yes, this IS an object oriented approach.  Your's is a procedural approach.

Comment: I showed how that breaks in my last comment. It breaks automatically if you don't allow the form to be auto-created or create multiple instances of it. But enough said - I've explained why I downvoted (because your code is simply a bad solution). My last comment also explains why in the first two sentences.

Comment: @KenWhite As I said, I have applications that dynamically create forms and have MULTIPLE instances of the same form, and it works beautifully, I suggest you try it before you criticize.  This is exactly the type of problem that CLASS methods were created for.

Comment: Um, no. It will not, and that's not an example of a proper class method. I've been using Delphi since version 1, and Turbo Pascal before that, so I have a little experience with it. But as I said, this is not a debate (and I've discussed it too long). I think it's a bad solution, downvoted it, and was courteous enough to explain why I did so. You're not going to change my mind, so we don't need to discuss it any further. :-) I don't downvote lightly (only 28% of my more than 7000 votes are downvotes); when I do, I'm pretty sure I should.

Comment: I really don't need your Delphi history.  I've worked with every version of Delphi and Turbo Pascal since version 5.0

Comment: The problem from my point of view is not so much the hardcoded name but the fact that you have to duplicate the same code for every form class that needs this ability. That's what IMHO makes the "procedural" approach much better in this case.